# MongoDB Nested objects with own Repository interface

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongoDB to load and save some simple domain classes. As a simple example lets say I have Factory and Product

```
@Document
public class Factory {
    @Id String id;
    String name;
    List<Product> products;
}

@Document
public class Product {
    @Id String id;
    String name;
    Date productionDate;
}
```

Ok, simple enough I can now create a `FactoryRepository`:

```
public interface FactoryQueryRepository extends MongoRepository<Factory, String> {}
```

This repository already has basic CRUD functionality to store and load Factories together with nested products. Now lets say I want to only retrieve a set of products for a given factory.

I now have two questions:

**A)** Can I somehow return **a list of products** instead of a **list of factories** in the FactoryQueryRepository like so:

```
@Query(value = "???")
public List<Product> findProductByFactoryName(String name);
```

**B)** Lets say my factory does not only have products but also employees, customers, suppliers, you name it ... Now if need to define a few special query methods for each of these nested collections then I soon end-up with a very big `FactoryQueryRepository` interface. So it would actually be more appropriate to create a new `...QueryRepositoy` for Product, Employee, Customer and so on. But when I try to do this, it seems it only works if I first save a stand alone Product object that is not nested inside a Factory. Is there a way that I can (similar to question A) define a `ProductQueryRepository` interface and use it to retrieve all Products that are nested inside a Factory by specifying some filter criteria of the Factory, something like this:

```
public interface ProductQueryRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {
    @Query(/* select products from factory where name = '?0' */)
    public List<Product> findProductsByFactoryName(String name);
}
```

Shoud I in this case rather make use of the `@DBRef` than to use nested objects?

Answer (score 1):

For your question A) - you should use MongoTemplate to write a custom query.

For your question B) you should try to avoid any references when using MongoDB. MongoDB only guarantees atomic writes on a single document, not across multiple documents. If you must use a reference then you should not use DBRef, you should implement the reference manually (this is mentioned explicitly in the docs http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)